# Vue3 Composition API and computed properties with v-model

Tags: vuejs3

```
<input type="text" :id="phone" v-model="phone" />
...
import { useStore, mapState } from 'vuex'
import {  onMounted, ref, computed } from 'vue'
export default {
    setup() {
        const store = useStore()
        const phone = computed(() => store.getters['getPhone'])
        ...
        return { phone }
...
}}
```

So if v-model is supposed to handle both the getter and the mutation, how does the mutation side work?  Or should I explicitly do this:

```
<input type="text" :id="phone" v-bind:value="phone" @input="setPhone" />
```

but then I would also need a wrapper function to call the mutuation in the vuex store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed properties that you wish to use with `v-model` should be set up as [writable computed properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#writable-computed) which will allow you to get and set the value independently.

```js
const phone = computed({
  get() {
    return store.getters['getPhone']
  },
  set(newValue) {
    store.dispatch('setPhone', newValue)
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh, cool!  Didn't know about that. Thanks, yoduh!